# Express loads controller infinit times and browser windows crashes when I use subpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angularjs

I'm currently working with angularJS and I try to build a homepage. My routeconfig looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('mml-annie', ['mmlServices']);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
  $location.html5Mode(true); //now there won't be a hashbang within URLs for browers that     support HTML5 history
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/team', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/team', 
    controller: TeamCtrl
}).

otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

For testing purposes my controler looks like this:

```
function TeamCtrl($scope, Team) {

console.log("TEST");
}
```

Everything I working fine except when my path get additions / fields. When I change `"/team"` to `"/team/team/test"` my app calls the controller until the app crashes. Not using html5 mode fixes the problem. But I would rather use the nice HTML5 mode without the hashbang.

The app runs on `node.js` with express which serves the angular app for all requests except API calls.

Do you have any idea what is happening? I have no clue...
Of course I can provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution is as follows:

My partials didn't have the relative path prefix `"/"`. So whenever i tried to advance in a path the server looked for a partials that wasn't there, for example: /team/partials/team

Node then sent the basic layout which had itself the ng-view div again and started all over.

Why do I always fiddle around for like 2 hours - then decide to write a question and 2 minutes later I find the answer....

Comment: I've been stuck on this one for a while too, so thanks for posting.  And as for your last question, don't worry, it happens to all of us - Murphy's Law.